# MS Teams not accepting task module payload

Tags: microsoft-teams

while trying to use the developer preview tasks module i got a strange issue.

Teams isn't showing my module, always telling me this in console:

```
<BotError>Error when processing invoke response: Payload is incorrect, field is in the wrong format: task.value
```

What I'm sending is this:

```
{
    "task": {
        "value": {
            "url": "https://<ourbaseserviceurl>",
            "title": "Microsoft Ignite 2018 Vision Keynote",
            "height": 700,
            "width": 1000,
            "fallbackUrl": "<ourbaseserviceurl"
        },
        "type": "message"
    }
}
```

Was trying to use the sample but even that doesn't seem to work properly atm. 
The URL is in allowedurls for the app and the same we use to communicate with the bot which is in general working fine.

Comment: Which [code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-overview#task-module-samples) did you try? Could you please tell us more details about the issue?

Comment: Hey Wajeed, used the sample on the documentation page. Just changed the URls to use my own.

Tried to just send a card and also to use my url (iframe task) but none worked. 

Teams always gives me above error saying payload incorrect no matter what i try or change :(

Comment: Can you please try this [Task Module sample manifest](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-nodejs/blob/master/TaskModule.zip)?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT thanks for that, that seems to work need to see why mine isn't.

Comment: Can you share your manifest file? You can reach use using any of the channels mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback

Comment: yea need to upload it, however, just realized even the simplest example you had there with just sending type message and value = "message text" does not work. 

Always getting the same payload wrong error.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bwuovnYPSNbGmwu-i_FzQ6eRIobdZhmc

Currently running on my develop machine, any place to chat about that, might be easier than here. 


 - send the bot any message in private
 - it will send back a message saying you're not logged in
 - there's two actions (login preview) (login old)
 - preview should bring up a task module

Comment: What is the current payload value that you are sending when you receive task/fetch action?

Comment: {
  "task": {
    "type": "message",
    "value": "Task complete!"
  }
}

Comment: stil doing anything @Wajeed-MSFT? need to shut that thing down for a while

Comment: I tried and got the same error. I'll investigate. Can you once try putting "continue" payload specified in answer below.

Comment: same error "payload is incorrect"

Comment: Could you please share the code where you are handling the invoke (task/fetch)?

Comment: like my backend code to find out if its task/fetch etc? We don't "really" handle that. We only have one case where a user is not authenticated and we receive task/fetch which is to show our own login modal. 

                    case ActivityTypes.Invoke:
                        return HandleInvokeMessagesNotAuthenticated(activity, user,cancellationToken);

and in there we just check if its a compose extension request or not and send back the payload as json(response)

Comment: Are you using Task module for compose extension? Are you plannig on using Task module for authentication?

Comment: we're not using compose as a task module or anything (just its within the same activitytype = invoke check) we want to use the task module for authentication but also for quite a few other things, i was just unable to make it work at all outside of using the demo you provided in zip

Comment: Could you please share the code where you are sending back the json payload?

Comment: yea that is right now pretty simple, we have the full json payload in a json file, read the file and return it, nothing inbetween.

        private string CreateLoginTask()
        {
            var adaptiveCard = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@".\Dialogs\Welcome\Resources\taskLogin.json");

            return adaptiveCard;
        }

         var returndata = CreateLoginTask();
                return Ok(returndata);

Comment: hmm something happened tho, its different today. I get the modal but its empty and says "Failed to load webview. Please check if the specified app is available." and in the console there's an error saying "cannot read property 'validdomains' of undefined" it never tries to actually load it, can't see any incoming request

Comment: Can you uninstall all app the instances and retry again? Aslo, I got 404 for **/config/config/login** page which you are loading in Task Module.

Comment: is there an easy way to completely uninstall the app instances? using the App Studio thing and just installing again seems to update the app. Also 404 was when the app wasn't running, can try again now

Comment: Wow...got it finally. 
removed everything i could from the app, removed all domains except one (would need to add more later again), and now it seems to magically work... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set the task type as **continue** while passing TaskInfo object. Here is the 
 [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-bots#the-flexibility-of-tasksubmit).

```
{
    "task": {
        "type": "continue"
        "value": {
            "url": "https://<ourbaseserviceurl>",
            "title": "Microsoft Ignite 2018 Vision Keynote",
            "height": 700,
            "width": 1000,
            "fallbackUrl": "https://<ourbaseserviceurl>"
        },
    }
}
```

Here is how you display the value in a popup message box:

```
{
  "task": {
    "type": "message",
    "value": "Message text"
  }
}
```

Please try and let us know if you face any issue.

Comment: Tried the sample that is on the page you linked
also tried to use continue/message but that didn't change anything